# Ride.py issue for testing prupose

Tags: python, robotframework

Here is the spec I used to install

1. Python 2.5.2
2. Pywin32-216
3. WxPython 2.9
4. Robot Framework 2.8.3
5. Robot Framework IDE 1.3
6. Selenium2Library 1.6.0
7. setuptoolsv0.9.6
8. selenium-3.0.0b2
9. decorator3.3.2
10. openpyxl/1.6.1
11. robotframework-excellibrary-0.0.2
12. xlrd 0.8.0
13. naturalsort 1.0.1

type>ride.py
the issues is :
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Python25\Scripts\ride.py", line 20, in 
>      from robotide import main  File
>   "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\robotide__init__.py", line 51
>   except ImportError as e: syntaxerror: invalid syntax

Hope someone can let me know the way to solve it..thanks

Comment: the path is : 
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Python25;C:\Python25\Scripts;
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages;
C:\jython2.5.3\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin;

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335323/python-25-ride-py) your classmate? They posted a couple minutes ago with the exact same list of libraries (same order and versions), and the same script name.

Comment: TigerhawkT3 ... do have any experience for my issue ? any suggestion or advice?

Comment: Yeah; work with your classmate.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Python to 2.7.

Read instructions here [RIDE wiki](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions#python)